Decode GPS tracker data format send to the server
I have tried to find any documentation regarding the data received from my GPS tracker. Being a Chinese model I could not find any clue to decode the string send by the GPS tracker.
The format is: 787811010867946050055804005a212200067c6d0d0a. From this string I found that 867946050055804 is the IMEA number, but unable to decode the others.

You need to check the documentation to find out what it is sending.

@IanTurton As I have mention already in my question I could not find the documentation being the Device a chinese model with nothing written on it. For this I could get the help from those who have gone through the format. Any thanks for your concern. I will be posting the details as soon as I know it.
